# Application Insights added ConnectedService.json file to my project, Do I have to deploy it to the production server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-application-insights

Follow up to this question:

[Application Insights added ConnectedService.json file to my project, what does this do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571423/application-insights-added-connectedservice-json-file-to-my-project-what-does-t)

When I create a deployment package, via "Publish..." option, the package also include the following folder and files:

Service References\Application Insights\ConnectedService.json

I do not want to deploy something that is not required at runtime. Do I have to include the folder and file in my production server deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Those files are only used by visual studio for its information, to know what services have been added and give you links back to them inside VS. None of that needs to be deployed.  those files can all be set to do not copy/etc.